# When a question is put on hold as off topic, why isn't there an explanation given in the iOS app?

Tags: support, on-hold-questions, ios-app

So I am asking this due to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616911/cycles-of-length-six-in-a-complete-bipartite-graph

This isn't the only post I have seen this in, where someone asks a question that to me seems perfectly suited for mathSE but it becomes closed as off topic. What I am wondering is 1. Why was this post put off topic, or what am I not understand about the MathSE guidelines? And 2. Is there a reason why explanations aren't given when a question is put on hold like this?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/i5wfUq3.png

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  I see. I am using the iPhone app and that section does not display! This makes so much more sense now. Thanks, I now know to check the question on Safari to see why something is being put on hold.

Comment: Wow, that's quite the oversight from the devs of that app then... They should really display the reason. (I don't have an iPhone so I can't check, are you sure it's not displayed anywhere?)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I just found a very small button on the bottom that displayed the reason after I clicked on it. I added that to my answer of this question to hopefully help others in the who have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *is* an explanation given. When you look at the closed question:

[image: closed question]

click the ⓘ button on the bottom right for more information:

[image: closure reason]

Answer (score 10):

To answer my own question, there is an explanation given to questions that are put on hold, but unfortunately the iPhone stack exchange app is not currently formatted to display those explanations outright. There is a small button on the very bottom right of the page that will display the reason, or you can open the question in your web browser to see the reason.